# Why am I getting error "numbers of columns of arguments do not match" for some model specifications but not others?

Tags: r, glm, lm, caret, variable-selection

I'm trying to use the caret function rfe for variable selection. One of the models I would like to use it on is a logistic regression. I'm trying to follow the example here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37830/how-do-you-get-lmfuncs-functions-of-the-rfe-function-in-caret-to-do-a-logistic-r

From what I've observed in the following models, I can get the rfe function to work with my binary response variable presence when using random forest, GAM or naive Bayes, but both the basic linear model function and my attempt at making a glm logistic regression function don't work when presence is the predictor. However, the basic linear regression works fine when I use a different continuous variable as the predictor. Why would this be?

The error I'm getting is

> Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
> numbers of columns of arguments do not match

I'm not sure why this would be happening when the input predictors and response come from the same dataframe.

```
library(caret)

rfcontrol <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs, # random forest
                      method = "repeatedcv", # repeated cv
                      repeats = 5, # number of repeats
                      number = 10) # number of folds

out_rf <- rfe(dat[,c(2:6)], dat[,1], sizes = c(1:5), rfeControl = rfcontrol)
#works

nbcontrol <- rfeControl(functions = nbFuncs, # random forest
                        method = "repeatedcv", # repeated cv
                        repeats = 5, # number of repeats
                        number = 10) # number of folds

out_nb <- rfe(dat[,c(2:6)], dat[,1], sizes = c(1:5), rfeControl = nbcontrol)
#works

gamcontrol <- rfeControl(functions = gamFuncs, # random forest
                        method = "repeatedcv", # repeated cv
                        repeats = 5, # number of repeats
                        number = 10) # number of folds

out_gam <- rfe(dat[,c(2:6)], dat[,1], sizes = c(1:5), rfeControl = gamcontrol)
#works


lmcontrol <- rfeControl(functions = gamFuncs, # random forest
                        method = "repeatedcv", # repeated cv
                        repeats = 5, # number of repeats
                        number = 10) # number of folds

out_lm <- rfe(dat[,c(3:6)], dat[,2], sizes = c(1:4), rfeControl = lmcontrol)
#works


out_lm2 <- rfe(dat[,c(2:6)], dat[,1], sizes = c(1:5), rfeControl = lmcontrol)
#doesn't work

glmFuncs <- lmFuncs

glmFuncs$fit=function (x, y, first, last, ...)  {   
  tmp <- as.data.frame(x)   
  tmp$y <- y   
  glm(y ~ ., data = tmp, family=binomial(link='logit'))
}

glmcontrol <- rfeControl(functions = glmFuncs, # random forest
                        method = "repeatedcv", # repeated cv
                        repeats = 5, # number of repeats
                        number = 10) # number of folds

out_glm <- rfe(dat[,c(2:6)], dat[,1], sizes = c(1:5), rfeControl = glmcontrol)
#doesn't work
```

Here is a sample of the dataset I'm using

```
dat <- structure(list(presence = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("FALSE", 
                                                                                                                 "TRUE"), class = "factor"), mean_annual_temp = c(-10L, -9L, -6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -8L, -5L, -13L, -10L, -10L, -12L, -14L, -10L, -9L, -10L, -17L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -10L, -12L, -17L, -11L, -17L, -9L, -13L, -11L, -17L, -10L, -10L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -10L, -12L, -11L, -11L, -10L, -13L, -17L, -12L, -10L, -13L, -12L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -12L, -11L, -15L, -6L, -10L, -14L, -12L, -12L, -5L, -12L, -16L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -16L, -12L, -19L, -19L, -13L, -18L, -12L, -14L, -10L, -9L, -14L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -11L, -15L, -14L, -12L, -11L, -11L, -10L, -6L, -14L, -5L, -6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -9L, -12L, -11L, -11L, -14L, -16L, -14L, -13L, -14L, -13L, -14L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -13L, -10L, -12L, -13L, -9L, -13L, -13L, -14L, -12L, -17L, -15L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -12L, -15L, -11L, -12L, -14L, -5L, -12L, -5L, -14L), min_temp_coldest_month = c(-33L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -31L, -26L, -32L, -25L, -37L, -36L, -33L, -35L, -35L, -33L, -33L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -32L, -37L, -30L, -36L, -37L, -32L, -38L, -30L, -36L, -32L, -38L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -36L, -32L, -30L, -36L, -32L, -34L, -34L, -32L, -38L, -34L, -30L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -34L, -35L, -35L, -33L, -37L, -27L, -36L, -36L, -35L, -36L, -26L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -35L, -36L, -37L, -36L, -41L, -41L, -34L, -39L, -36L, -39L, -30L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -30L, -38L, -33L, -37L, -38L, -35L, -34L, -34L, -34L, -27L, -38L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -27L, -27L, -30L, -35L, -36L, -33L, -39L, -37L, -37L, -36L, -36L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -34L, -39L, -34L, -31L, -36L, -37L, -31L, -33L, -36L, -38L, -34L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -37L, -36L, -36L, -37L, -36L, -36L, -38L, -27L, -33L, -25L, -38L
                                                                                                                                                                  ), temp_annual_range = c(49L, 49L, 41L, 50L, 39L, 52L, 52L, 48L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           50L, 46L, 48L, 50L, 48L, 44L, 42L, 51L, 44L, 47L, 44L, 43L, 52L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           44L, 47L, 52L, 48L, 45L, 51L, 47L, 49L, 53L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 42L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           46L, 51L, 51L, 47L, 47L, 42L, 52L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 42L, 50L, 43L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           45L, 51L, 51L, 48L, 46L, 45L, 52L, 52L, 42L, 47L, 51L, 48L, 47L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           52L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 42L, 52L, 42L, 41L, 47L, 51L, 53L, 49L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           52L, 47L, 50L, 52L, 48L, 45L, 52L, 46L, 46L, 52L, 51L, 49L, 45L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           51L, 52L, 48L, 45L, 47L, 52L, 47L, 53L, 51L, 52L, 42L, 45L, 39L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           51L), mean_temp_wettest_Q = c(7L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         6L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         8L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         7L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         6L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 5L), mean_temp_driest_Q = c(-28L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -21L, -22L, -26L, -17L, -31L, -22L, -22L, -30L, -30L, -22L, -21L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -24L, -33L, -25L, -31L, -33L, -27L, -33L, -24L, -31L, -27L, -33L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -22L, -27L, -22L, -31L, -28L, -29L, -28L, -27L, -33L, -29L, -25L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -29L, -31L, -30L, -28L, -32L, -23L, -21L, -32L, -30L, -31L, -22L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -30L, -31L, -32L, -30L, -37L, -36L, -28L, -34L, -31L, -33L, -25L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -25L, -32L, -28L, -32L, -32L, -30L, -29L, -29L, -28L, -23L, -32L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -22L, -23L, -24L, -31L, -30L, -27L, -33L, -32L, -32L, -31L, -31L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -29L, -33L, -29L, -18L, -30L, -32L, -21L, -28L, -31L, -33L, -29L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -33L, -31L, -31L, -32L, -30L, -30L, -33L, -22L, -29L, -19L, -33L
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```